# What casing do styled components use when passing attributes to html or web-component elements

Tags: javascript, html, styled-components, web-component, stenciljs

What casing do styled-components use when passing attributes to the element.

Lets say you have this HTML with attributes:

```
<div data-justin='my name' class='text' data-selected=false> </div>

              or a web-component like this:

<web-component a-long-attr-justin='my name' tons-of-data-selected=false> </div>
```

Then you have this as a styled component:

```
export const StyledComp = styled('div')

export const StyledComp = styled('web-component')
```

Now I have passed my attributes in kabob case. Question is when the styled component passes those given attributes back to the HTML element or web-component Element what casing is used? Is it Camel case, Pascal, snake case?

Comment: Sorry don't use stencil or styled components; but sounds to me its an easy test you can do yourself in 5 minutes

Comment: I tried for a while but i wasn't able to get my web components to work with Reacts styled-components, Maybe that's it right there...Reacts styled-components it's in the name. Huh?